# Not really understanding retrieving marker location from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I looked for an answer and tried a lot of tutorials but i still can't get it right.I'm working on an app in which user can add marker to the map, and all the other users will see the marker. But i can't make it work because the markers from database never show.

this is my code for reading from database:

```
mLocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                MarkerLocation markerLocation = dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue(MarkerLocation.class);
                for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                double latitude = (double) (s.child("lat").getValue());
                double longitude = (double) ((s.child("lng").getValue()));
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and firebase database look like this:

- application

  ```
    -location
          -marker
               -latitude:43.849
               -longitude:-109.737
  ```

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If not, please add a screenshot of your database structure.

Comment: I need 10 rep to upload aj image :D And i don't have that

Comment: Use https://imgbb.com/ and provide the link.

Comment: https://ibb.co/2MvMPsW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add all the markers from your database on the map according to your actual schema, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference locationRef = rootRef.child("location");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            MarkerLocation markerLocation = ds.getValue(MarkerLocation.class);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLocation.getLatitude(), markerLocation.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            Log.d(TAG, markerLocation.getLatitude() + ", " +  markerLocation.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
locationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

If you are setting the values directly onto public fields, please change the following line of code:

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLocation.getLatitude(), markerLocation.getLongitude());
```

to

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(markerLocation.latitude, markerLocation.longitude);
```

Comment: Do you have an error or what? What is the bevaviour? Does the Log statement from  my edited answer print something?

Comment: The map starts normally and everithing works as its supposed to only the markers are not diplayed on the map... Errors im getting are in these screenshots https://ibb.co/wMPrDjg
https://ibb.co/ZHwW7xx

Comment: I cannot see any exceptions. Please tell me, does the Log statement `Log.d(TAG, markerLocation.getLatitude() + ", " +  markerLocation.getLongitude());` from my edited answer print something in the logcat?

Comment: No I don't think so, can't find anything like that but there is an update....we  now display markers from database but they all appear in the same spot on the map but no marker has latlng of that spot. Any ideas? sorry for not making it easy but I'm pretty new to this whole java thing.

Comment: Let's stick to one question at a time. You say I don't think... So be sure and take a look at the logcat. Are the coordinates from the database displayed in the logcat? I cannot help you, if don't help me.

Comment: no the coordinates from the database are not displayed in logcat

Comment: Oh, you're right. It was my misteke. It should be: `MarkerLocation markerLocation = ds.getValue(MarkerLocation.class);` as in my updated answer. Please try again. Is it something printed now in the logcat?

Comment: well mister, with this last comment of yours I would like to thank you for your asistance because all the markers from database are now displayed on the map...Thank you very much

Comment: Would you be kind enough to maybe help me with one more thing?

Comment: @MišoBendík It won't be a problem so please post another fresh question, so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: I already have.. it's this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361355/average-rating-in-firebase-database but nobody replied

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                MarkerLocation markerLocation = dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue(MarkerLocation.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(markerLocation.latitude, markerLocation.longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));

                }
            }
```

Comment: No sorry. But I changed that because i was trying something different and afterwards forgot to change it back, but even with that correct it still doesn't display a marker

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is correct you should be able to show a marker with:

```
LatLng loc = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc)
            .title("Marker"));
```

Also, if your firebase data structure is the one you posted before, take a look at the keys: you are using

```
double latitude = (double) (s.child("lat").getValue());
double longitude = (double) ((s.child("lng").getValue()));
```

But it should be:

```
double latitude = (double) (s.child("latitude").getValue());
double longitude = (double) ((s.child("longitude").getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not getting updates because you're using the addListenerForSingleValueEvent API, which will do a 1-time query of the database node.  If you want to hook up a listener such that you can receive an update *every* time the node changes, then you need to use the addValueEventListener API.